# How to prefetch images from ionic tags for a PWA?

Tags: ionic4, angular8

**PROBLEM OBSERVATION**

I'm trying to eagerly load the app and the it's images. In Google Chrome I can set the Ionic4/Angular8 PWA to offline. I still can browse all the pages since I loaded them lazy - AND - the `PreloadAllModules` is imported to the app-routing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

However, the icons, which I use `<ion-icon slot="start" name="Notifications"></ion-icon>` are not prefetched and thus will not appear in offline mode (if the page was not visited before).

I do understand that prefetched images need to be set in the ngsw-config.json file, which will be turned into the ngsw.json after the build command run. That file lists all the images and other statics to prefetch.

**DEAD-END APPROACHES with the ngsw-config.json**

- I quickly thought about prefetching the entire svg folder. That is almost half a MB.
- Adding each single image to the ngsw-config.json file. Cumbersome and prone to forget new icons.

**QUESTION**

- Is there a specific Ionic 4 approach to this that detects what icons to prefetch?
- Any Angular 8 approach to this?

Comment: `I quickly thought about prefetching the entire svg folder.` why is this a dead end using ngxw-config.json ?

Comment: @bhantol because I don't want to fetch the entire folder. Fetching the entire folder is more than just the small SVG, it contains also a pre-flight requests and then the real GET request with a header overhead.